# Without events, how does the browser know it is executing javaScript as opposed to regular HTML?

Tags: javascript

A question on my javaScript homework goes as follows:

For non event JavaScript, how does the browser know it is executing JavaScript as opposed to regular HTML.

I'm having difficulty understanding what my professor means by this question. I believe she is asking how does the browser know how to differentiate JS from HTML without any JS events. If anyone knows the answer to this question, your help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You don't "execute" HTML, you just render it.

Comment: That question makes very little sense, unless he's asking how to embed standalone JS inside an HTML document.  (in which case it's very poorly phrased)

Comment: This is like asking how you know that you're dialing the phone, as opposed to reading the phone book.

Comment: Or with event attributes (like `onLoad=''`)

Comment: Yes, my professor isn't that great at articulating questions. Thank you ToddBFisher, I believe that's the answer she was looking for.

Comment: You might want to ask your professor for clarification. On the other hand, if that's the question she asked verbatim, then maybe ask some classmates.

Comment: Or if it is asked to resolve a URI that starts with `javascript:` (and I agree this seems like a really odd question)

Comment: sounds like a trick question... professor wants to see how many come up with silly answers

Answer (score 0):

You probably have HTML basis. In HTML, how do you tell a text is bold? You'd write

```
<strong>bold.text</strong>
```

Then how do you tell the browser it is javascript?

```
<script type="text/javascript">//code here</script>
```

I believe this is what he asked?

Answer (score 0):

with a `<script>` tag the browser will expect JavaScript and not HTML.

Comment: Figured since other's agreed my comment was the solution, here it is in answer form. I hope that was helpful Snubber so you can resolve this question.